# Which type makes up the majority of Pokemon in Sun/Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

As I stated, which type (water, fire, etc.) of Pokemon make up the majority of Pokemon in the latest games, Sun and Moon?

Answer (score 8):

## Water

Counting manually using Bulbapedia's [Handbook Pokedex](http://bulbahandbook.bulbagarden.net/pokemonsunmoon/pokedex/regional), Using the 'Refine' function to restrict the list by type, Water has 60 entries in Sun/Moon, higher than all other types. Flying comes in second at 50.

This includes different formes of the same Pokemon that may share a Pokedex number as well as event exclusives.

---

This also holds true for the National Pokedex. According to Bulbapedia's entry on the [**Water**](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Water_(type)) type:

> As of Generation VII, there are 133 Water-type Pokémon or **16.6% of all Pokémon** (counting those that are Water-type in at least one of their forms), making it the most common of the eighteen types.

This is followed by **[Normal](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Normal_(type))** type in 2nd place:

> As of Generation VII, there are 109 Normal-type Pokémon or 13.6% of all Pokémon, making it the second most common type after Water.

As for the *least*-used type, that would be [**Ice**](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ice_(type)):

> As of Generation VII, there are 40 Ice-type Pokémon or 5.0% of all Pokémon (counting those that are Ice-type in at least one of their forms, including Alola Forms), making it the rarest type.